# SQL - JOIN with MAX(created_at)

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

## Problem

I have 3 tables: customers, companies and calls.

A customer has many Companies, and a Company has many calls. (both one to many).

The current status of a Company is the result of the last call for the company (MAX(created_at)).

Now I want a list of all companies for a customer with the columns of the last call in the results.

## Needed Result

The result should be:
company.*, lastcall.*,

- There could be calls with the same created_at date. Then there should be only 1 row in de result.
- Not all companies has a call yet, the company should still be in the result and the columns of the call should be NULL. (left join)

## Tables

**customers**
- id (int, primary key)
- name (varchar)
- address (varchar)
- city (varchar)

**companies**
- id (int, primary key)
- customer_id (int)
- name (varchar)
- address (varchar)
- city (varchar)

**calls**
- id (int, primary key)
- company_id (int)
- result (varchar)
- created_at (datetime)

## Attempt

A query which didn't work I came up with is:

```
SELECT * FROM companies co  
LEFT JOIN calls ca ON co.id = ca.company_id 
WHERE co.customer_id = ? 
GROUP BY co.id  
HAVING ca.created_at = (SELECT max(ll.created_at) FROM calls ll WHERE ll.company_id = co.id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I found the answer.
This one gives the correct result, and still fast enough (0.27 seconds)

```
SELECT co.*, v.* 
FROM companies co 
LEFT JOIN 
( 
    SELECT 
    ca.* 
    FROM calls ca 
    JOIN 
    ( 
        SELECT 
        company_id, 
        MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at 
        FROM calls 
        GROUP BY company_id 
    ) t 
    ON ca.company_id = t.company_id AND ca.created_at = t.max_created_at
    GROUP BY company_id
) v ON co.id = v.company_id
```

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3):

you should just join a select so that way you arent trying to re evaluate the select.

```
SELECT co.id, co.label, ca.result, ca.id, t.date_created as most_recent
FROM companies co
LEFT JOIN
(   SELECT MAX(created_at) as date_created, company_id
    FROM calls
    GROUP BY company_id
) t ON t.company_id = co.id
JOIN calls ca ON ca.company_id = t.company_id AND t.date_created = ca.created_at
WHERE co.customer_id = ?
```

### EDIT:

the issue is you have more than one call per company at the max date. to test this just pull out one customer and company and look at the results.

```
SELECT co.id, co.label, ca.result, ca.id, ca.created_at as most_recent_date
FROM companies co
LEFT JOIN
(   SELECT MAX(created_at) as date_created, company_id
    FROM calls
    GROUP BY company_id
) t ON t.company_id = co.id
JOIN calls ca ON ca.company_id = t.company_id AND t.date_created = ca.created_at
WHERE co.customer_id = ? AND co.id = ?
```

run this query and specify a specific company. look at the `move_recent_date` column and see if the date is the same for each row and if it is the max date

Comment: This doesn't show the lastcall result and lastcall id

Comment: @overflowed it does now

Comment: result and id are not in an aggregated or group by clause this will still not work

Comment: @overflowed oops sorry forgot to join calls. fixed. thnx for the notes

Comment: you would need to join calls after your left join and you need to include the max(created_at) from the t table in the join on the calls table

Comment: Wo! A lot of good answers in a couple minutes. Thx! I always only use simple joins. I will post when evaluated them all.

Comment: This one is very fast (0.05 seconds)! But it doesn't give the right result when there  is more as one call with the same created_at time. (Happens when data is imported) There is a row for each call.

Comment: @blablabla oops my mistake I had the JOIN on the wrong condition. try it now, It should work and still be just as fast :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell I have tried the query. It is indeed fast (0.05 seconds) but I still don't get the right result. I currently have 6388 companies in the database and I get 19037 results. That means there are multiple rows for the same company in the resultset.

Comment: @blablabla thats because im incorporating the customers table. you are getting all customers for that organization too. i just edited to remove the customers. let me know if that works :)

Comment: I still get 19037 results

Comment: @blablabla then that means you have a lot of calls made on the max day. if the max(created_at) has 5 calls per company then that would be 45k approx rows returned... you can add a GROUP BY but that is pointless as it would be returning random data in the other rows. see my edit for a check to see if its true

Comment: I modified the needed result. When there are multiple calls with max(created_at) I need just 1 (Could be the one with the lowest ID). This only happens when there are calls imported, so normally it will not happen.

Comment: @blablabla if all you want is just one row returned for each then just try it with a group by at the end of my query and see what happens. it may still be faster since I'm not doing two left joins. i use a regular join because it is joining on the left joined table already so it should still have nulls in there.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by joining on `calls` twice, the first time being in a subquery where you retrieve the last call date for each company:

```
SELECT * FROM companies co  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, MAX(created_at) AS last_call FROM calls GROUP BY company_id) AS last_calls ON last_calls.company_id = co.id
LEFT JOIN calls ca ON ca.company_id = last_calls.company_id AND ca.created_at = last_calls.last_call
WHERE co.customer_id = ? 
GROUP BY co.id
```

Comment: you have a syntax error :) the column is created_at not last_call :) just as a fyi

Comment: Actually, the error was writing `ca.create_at` instead of `ca.created_at`. I couldn't test it since I didn't have the actual database. It's fixed.

Comment: yea that is correct I wasn't looking at the alias :)

Comment: This gives the correct result! The performance is only a lot worse. (90 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You could double join to the lastcall table, like in this example:

```
select companies.id, companies.name , lastcall.id, lastcall.result from companies
inner join (select max(created_at) as lastcall, company_id from calls group by company_id) maxcalls 
on (companies.id = maxcalls.company_id)
inner join lastcall on (lastcall = created_at and companies.id = lastcall.company_id)
where customer_id = ?


select companies.* , ca.* from companies 
inner join (select max(created_at) as lastcall, company_id from calls group by company_id) maxcalls on (companies.id = maxcalls.company_id)    
inner join calls ca on (maxcalls.lastcall = ca.created_at and companies.id = ca.company_id)
where customer_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a subselect to get max created from calls and use that as join condition to company and calls tables.

```
SELECT
    co.id AS company_id,
    co.name AS company_name,
    ca.id AS lastcall_id,
    ca.result AS lastcall_result
FROM companies AS co
LEFT JOIN calls AS ca
    ON co.id = ca.company_id
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            company_id,
            MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at
        FROM calls
        GROUP BY company_id
    ) AS max_created_per_company
    ON ca.company_id = max_created_per_company.company_id
    AND ca.created_at = max_created_per_company.created_at
WHERE co.customer_id = ?
```